# Google Map implementation not working on Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, safari, implementation

I am implementing a google map on the contact page of this website: 
http://www.vqt.ch/dev/?lang=fr&page=contact

The map displays in the rectangle on the top of the page. Everything is working fine on Firefox, but nothing is displayed on Safari & Chrome...

Here is the way I implement it:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA8yt4eBY5BILk0ExOfUVIuxTtIfr4IreHJHupahKP7IIqKlsN7BQG4crqM32UzthNoFP_54xDooNNNQ&amp;sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

        function createMarker(point,text) {
          var marker = new GMarker(point);
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {   marker.openInfoWindowHtml(text);  });
          return marker;
        }
        function load() {
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                var Lat=46.983707;
                var Lng=6.904106;
                var Zoom=13;
                var TextAffiche="<strong>VQT<\/song><br/>Verre & Quartz Technique SA<br/><br/>Rue de Maillefer 11d<br/>2000 Neuchatel";

                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("contactMap"));
                    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(Lat,Lng ),Zoom );
                    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());
                    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

                var point = new GLatLng(Lat,Lng);

                var new_icon = new GIcon()  
                    new_icon.image = "http://www.vqt.ch/gmap_marker.png";  
                    new_icon.size = new GSize(50, 32);  
                    new_icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(0,0);  
                    new_icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(0,0); 

                    var opt;  
                    opt = {};  
                    opt.icon = new_icon;  
                    opt.draggable = false;
                    opt.clickable = true; 
                    opt.dragCrossMove = false;  

                var marker = new GMarker(point,opt);//createMarker(point,TextAffiche);
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(TextAffiche)
            }
        }
        $("body").attr("onload", "load()");
        $("body").attr("onunload", "GUnload()");

    //]]>
    </script>
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="normalContent">
            <div id="contactMap" class="borderedImages"></div>
        </div>
```

Do you know what is wrong in there? I really don't understand why it's working somewhere and not working somewhere else...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you show the CSS for the divs you are using? Do you get some errors in the console? Make sure your scipt is executed on document ready.

Comment: I just tried to make a version with only the map, and no other html or css. 

The problem is still the same... 
http://www.vqt.ch/dev/google_map_debug/ (everything is viewable on the page source)

May be the problem this call?
$("body").attr("onload", "load()");
$("body").attr("onunload", "GUnload()");

I tried to put all the javascript in the <head>, but the it just don't work anymore...

Does somebody here have an exemple of simple implementation working on safari?

Thank you for your help!
David

Answer (score 2):

I restarted from a tutorial and it's now working: 
http://www.vqt.ch/dev/google_map_debug/

The main difference is the call of the load function, which now is on the body attributes:

```
  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

So I guess the problem was here...
Thank you for your help!

---